# <a href> tag not working in a program with jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, href

I am using jQuery and jQuery mobile to make a page and but the hyper link is not working in it. I made another page just to try with tag, but still the same problem. tag is not opening the page it is referred to.

here's the code.

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>
            Entry Details
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Date:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Time:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Repeat:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="repeat1" id="repeat1" value="Daily">
                    <label for="repeat1">
                        Daily
                    </label>
                    <input type="radio" name="repeat2" id="repeat2" value="Weekly">
                    <label for="repeat2">
                        Weekly
                    </label>
                    <input type="radio" name="repeat3" id="repeat3" value="Monthly">
                    <label for="repeat3">
                        Monthly
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button value="submit">
            <a href="F:\Package\Assgnmnts\newAdd.html">Submit </a>
        </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

this problem is same in newAdd.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not nest an a tag within the button tag. Instead, the submit destination should be set as the form tag's "action" attribute.

Comment: Thanks khior, i have removed form tag and nested button tag in <a href> tag. it works now